# How do I backup/restore my Empathy logs?

Tags: 10.10, empathy, backup

I found a folder called `~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs`. If I just copy that folder, and paste it into a new installation, will my logs be preserved? Or will they not be associated with the new accounts? I don't want to risk it until I know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that will work on Ubuntu 10.10.

On 10.04 (and I assume older versions), the folder you need to copy is `~/.local/share/Empathy/logs/`
.

If you use nautilus (the default file manager) to copy/paste the folder, you will need to allow it to 'merge' the folders when you paste.

You could use this command to backup:

```
cp -r ~/.local/share/Empathy/logs/* /path/to/backup/directory/empathy-logs
```

or  `cp -r ~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs/* /path/to/backup/directory/empathy-logs`

And this command to restore:

```
 cp -r /path/to/backup/directory/empathy-logs/* ~/.local/share/Empathy/logs/
```

or   `cp -r /path/to/backup/directory/empathy-logs/* ~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs/`

Comment: There is no folder `~/.local/share/Empathy` on my Maverick install. Only `~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs`, which definitely contains my Empathy logs (I can read the XML files in plain text to make sure).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the 10.10 tag. I have now corrected my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs` is the path to the empathy logs.  The version of Empathy in Maverick uses telepathy-logger to log.

I haven't tested restoring those, but I think account names are consistent, so should work.

Comment: Just tested on a fresh install of the Maverick beta. The account/folder names are consistent, and everything worked as expected.